# list view inside relative layout not taking entire screen height

Tags: android, android-layout

The code is not coming in the full screen...
The size of the list view is not fitting the whole screen.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutassigt"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="340dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewassignments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_bottom"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/ID_NO_ASSIGNMENT_MSG"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbarassignmentload"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_left_frag_assignment_error_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Parent of the `ListView` is the `RelativeLayout` in your case whose height is set to `android:layout_width="250dp"`. So the max heigh the listview can take is `250dp`. Change that to `match_parent`

Comment: One more question formated like that and you are flagged for spaming pal. Appreciate others time,  don't repeat same line of the text because you are frustrated something didn't worked out for you.

Comment: @hrskrs I am agree with you at any point

Comment: use match_parent in width and height in relative layout and remove padding from listview.

Answer (score 2):

You have hard coded your root layout. Please make it match parent.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update your parent layout .

```
 <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearlayoutassigt"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

===============================================
Try this way..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listviewassignments"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptyText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbarassignmentload"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/student_left_frag_assignment_error_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


</LinearLayout>
```

If it is not works let me inform

Answer (score 0):

*This xml is poorly coded. Post image explaining how the design should look.*

TextViews are **match_parent** so because of **z-ordering** you are seeing the textView only change to **wrap_content**. Also there is no relativeness!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutassigt"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="340dp" />
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutassigt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```